# Javascript VISIBLE and REQUIRED field upon radio button choice on form

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to write a function that will show a field based on the choice of a radio button, AND make that field required.  BUT, if the the said choice is not made, then the field is hidden and not required.  I have the toggle view working - meaning it shows if the first radio button is chosen, but I have not been able to get it to be required.  The field SSN is only visible if the choice 1 of field SocialSecurity is chosen.

Here is the radio button on the form:

Do you have a Social Security Number?

- (choice 1) As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.
- (choice 2)Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.

Please look at my code:

```
$('.field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]').on("change", function()
{
  switch($(this).val())
  {
    case 'As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.':
                $('.field.SSN').show();
                $('.field.SSN').attr('required', '');
                $('.field.SSN').attr('data-error', 'Please enter your Social Security Number.');
      break;

    case 'Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.':
        $('.field.SSN').hide();
        $('.field.SSN').removeAttr('required');
        $('.field.SSN').removeAttr('data-error');

      break;
  }     
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it depends on your `jquery` version why the `attr` function does not work. Instead of calling the removeAttr method, can you also set the value to false explicitly? Try this out:

```
.attr(attribute,value); // syntax

.attr("required", true);
// is the equivalent for required="required"

.attr("required", false);
```

// Using .prop

```
.prop(property,value) // syntax

.prop("required", true);
// is the equivalent for required=""

.prop("required", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 $('.field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]').on("change", function()
{
  switch($(this).val())
  {
    case 'As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.':
                $('.field.SSN').show();
                $('.field.SSN').prop('required', true);
                $('.field.SSN').prop('data-error', 'Please enter your Social Security Number.');
      break;

    case 'Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.':
        $('.field.SSN').hide();
        $('.field.SSN').prop('required', false);

      break;
  }     
});
```